# Flattening List of Lists Column Following Pandas Groupby

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby, flatten

I have a pandas dataframe containing IDs and Codes which are of type list:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4], 'Code': [['A', 'B'], ['A', 'B'], ['A', 'B', 'C'], 
                   ['A'], ['A'], ['A', 'C'], ['D', 'C'], ['A', 'D']]})
```

I would like to groupby ID and get a list of all codes associated with each ID:

```
df_groupby = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby('ID')['Code'].apply(list))
```

After executing the above code I have a dataframe at the ID level with the 'Code' column transformed to a list of lists.  How would I flatten each list of lists within the 'Code' column such that I have a list of all codes associated with each ID?

Answer (score 2):

Try this.You can use [np.hstack](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html) to Stack arrays in sequence horizontally.

```
import numpy as np
df_groupby["Code"] = df_groupby["Code"].apply(lambda x: np.hstack(x))
```

or

```
df_groupby["Code"] = df_groupby["Code"].apply(np.hstack)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use list comprehension:

```
df = df.groupby('ID')['Code'].agg(lambda x: [z for y in x for z in y]).to_frame()
print(df)
                     Code
ID                       
1   [A, B, A, B, A, B, C]
2                  [A, A]
3            [A, C, D, C]
4                  [A, D]
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question.  Applying numpy's hstack does the trick:

```
df_groupby['Code'] = df_groupby['Code'].apply(np.hstack)
```